# NextJS: Vanilla JavaScript, Possible or not?

Tags: javascript, next.js, nextjs-image

Newbie to ReactJS and NextJS here, was wondering if it is possible to add JavaScript to HTML classNames in NextJS.
For example trying to create a parallax effect requires a certain package to be installed through npm to be able to get parallax working.

Example question: How do I add a javascript effect to this image code?

```
<Image className={styles.bg}
    src="/../public/bg.jpg"
    // width={2049}
    // height={2049}
    // objectFit="cover"
    layout="fill"
    quality={100}
  />
```

So my question is how do I add the below code to make my javascript effect work:

```
let bg = document.getElementById("bg");

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
      var value = window.scrollY;

      bg.style.top = value * 0.5 + 'px';
      moon.style.left = -value * 0.5 + 'px';
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: Just figured out that it's not possible this way.
NextJS does not allow the direct control of the DOM as it is SSR.
Because of this you have to import React and from React you need to also import useRef, useEffect and useState. 

If you're asking what I am trying to achieve, I am trying to create a parallax effect.